# C# How do I access method of nested class trough object of parent class?

Tags: c#, nested-class

```
public class City
{
  public class Population
  {
    public int number;
    public void change(int amount)
    {
      number = amount;
    }
  public class Buildings
  {...}
  public class Military
  {...}
}
```

and let's say that in another class, i have

```
public City[] PlayerCities = new City[6];
```

if I try to do stuff like `PlayerCities[0].Population.Change(4)` it doesn't work.

PS: I am a beginner, I couldn't think of other implementations - that is why i use nested classes - it seemed to make sense to me

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, you're trying to use a nested class as a property. You either make population a property or the array needs to be City.Population[] . Why are you using nested classes?

Comment: Those seem more fitting as properties - one of the characteristics of a City is that it has a population, it has a collection of buildings etc etc.  e.g. `London.Population = 8,000,000... var b = London.Buildings.Count()`

Comment: Look, I was just trying to give you food for thought. I agree with the other comments. Why does population need to be a class? I messed up my first comment anyway, I meant does `City` have a `Population`... only the class definition is there.

Comment: [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Comment: If want to continue with a nested solution then look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `Population` object before you can access its methods. Another way of doing that would be to make Change a static variable(which wouldn't make sense in your case but important to know about).

In the code below I created an auto property of `Population` inside of `City`

```
public class City
{
  public Population Population {get; set;}
  public class Population
  {
    public int number;
    public void change(int amount)
    {
      number = amount;
    }
  public class Buildings
  {...}
  public class Military
  {...}
}
```

after adding, you can do `PlayerCities[0].Population.Change(4)`